# Xamarin Forms SQLite namespace cannot be found despite NUget installing it.

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a two prong problem. First, and most annoyingly, using Xamarin forms .Net Standard Library when I attempt to use SQLite it says "The type of namespace name SQLite could not be found. Even though I clearly have it installed (see pictures below).

This means I basically can't do any saving to a local DB.

I installed sqlite-net-pc l 1.4.118 to my entire solution, and it shows up in each of the individual projects.

Second. When I attempt to add a DB-Path parameter to my public App method, I get an error in the Android project saying App does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument. Again despite clearly having a method (see attached photos).

Any ideas what the heck is going on ?

[Screen shot of SQLite being clearly installed in the Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4t10.png)

[Image of my App method with a string parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uz9j.png)

[Image of my calling the above method in my Android project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eeA9.png)

[Error list on Build Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l9mD.png)

Comment: Did you add a sqlite-net-pcl to android and iOS project ?

Comment: Yes. I used the option that added them to each project automatically

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you problem is related to you project folder. Try to move you project more close to the root of your disk. That will solve the build error probably.